# How to send api token for each user in ajax header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, api, token

In Laravel project, I get my api token from database and use it in ajax header in local environment. know I want to set api token in header for each user. How can I do this?

Here is my ajax:

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
                url: url,
                headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer my_token "},
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                success: function( data){
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
 </script>
```

Now I want to send each use token with header not just for one person.

Answer (score 1):

save it in local storage when you login or sign up like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('token',your_token)
```

and when you need to send it just make this line like this:

```
headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token')},
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. but I find another solution that doesn't need header for every ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: YourData,
    success: function(data){
      console.log('succes: '+data);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by **"Now I want to send each use token with header not just for one person."**
But if you are referring sending token with every ajax request,
You can do it by adding the script below, It's similar to [Laravel X-CSRF-TOKEN setup](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) this is just one-time setup. With every ajax request it will automatically add the token.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token'),
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I put this in meta tag:

```
<meta meta name="api_token" content="{{ (Auth::user()) ? Auth::user()- 
>api_token : '' }}">
```

And in script part:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $('meta[name="api_token"]').attr('content'),
    }
});
```